# How to keep original function return value after using Variadic Macros?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

It is a VS2010 C++ project. I have a list of APIs:

1. `int a = API1("para1", "para2", ...);`
2. `double a = API2("para1", "para2", ...);`
3. `float a = API3("para1", "para2", ...);`

Now, I need to add a new API, `APINEW()`. As long as above APIs are run, APINEW need to called as follow. Therefore, I decided to use the Variadic Macros as shown below:

`#define newAPI1(...) ( API1(__VA_ARGS__); APINEW() )`

`#define newAPI2(...) ( API2(__VA_ARGS__); APINEW() )`

`#define newAPI3(...) ( API3(__VA_ARGS__); APINEW() )`

However, I will not correctly get the return value from my API1, API2 and API3.

I am trying to use the following code since I know the marco will always return the last item, but it cannot pass the compile.

`#define newAPI1(...) ( {auto a = API1(__VA_ARGS__); APINEW(); a} )`

I wonder is there a way that can make it correct?
(The reason I use new name (e.g. newAPI1) is to avoid comflict because in the project, it may have other macros that overload the existing API1, API2 and API3.)

Another question:
is there a way to pass the combination of

1. first parameter of `__VA_ARGS__`
2. `__FUNCTION__`
3. `__LINE__`

into the APINEW parameter => `APINEW(first parameter of __VA_ARGS__ + __FUNCTION__ + __LINE__)`

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps.

```
template <typename FirstArg, typename... Args>
auto API1Helper(const char* file, int line, FirstArg&& first_arg, Args&&... args) {
  auto ret = API1(first_arg, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  APINEW(first_arg, file, line);
  return ret;
}

#define newAPI1(...) API1Helper(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Though this may require a compiler newer than VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried and it works in vs2015 but failed in vs2010. I wonder is there any other way that fits the vs2010?

Comment: Does vs2010 support variadic templates at all? E.g. does this compile `template <typename... Args> void f(Args&&... args) {}`

Comment: The answer is no. VS2010 does not support templates in this format.

Comment: Well, you know the signature of `API1`, I presume. Rather than making `API1Helper` a template, make it a normal function with parameters matching those of API1, plus `file` and `line`.